# How does Google search work

Tags: google-search

I recently learnt about FNV hashing, and out of pure curiosity, I just searched the magic constant `2166136261` in Google.

I am very surprised to find that the Wikipedia page of [FNV hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function) shows up as the third searching result. However, when I open the wiki page I found the constant `2166136261` is not appeared in the article (even not in the source code).

How could Google search get this result, or does it "know" the relationship between FNV and `2166136261`?

**EDIT**

To make sure the searching result is not affected by my searching history, I also tried in incognito mode on google.com.hk, the Wiki result still show up as the 10th result instead of the 3rd.

Also it is very different from the 1st to 9th results, as most of them are sourcecode like `unsigned hash = 2166136261u ...`

In this case, I am not sure whether Google sees 2166136261 and Fowler–Noll–Vo are "synonyms" (or they are somehow related) , as clearly a search on "Fowler–Noll–Vo" will return very different results.

Comment: It's a shame people are voting to close this. Yeah, it's a broad question, but it's genuinely interesting and a great question. I'm not sure you can narrow it down easily. (With the exception of the title)

Comment: thats too bad... I admit this title is poor, but I am just not sure how to be more specific without adding a whole paragraph in title. and I even dont know which site to post this question ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the technical explanation, but I can offer some reasoning.

In the past, I've searched for terms that have alternate titles. For example, my wife has a Nissan Tiida. In the US, the same car is called a Nissan Versa. Searching for `Tiida` will include pages with the word `Versa`, even though the term `Tiida` is not present on the page.

So somewhere, Google has some smarts to figure out related/associated words, and include these in results. Alternately, they might just have a big, manual list of associated words. Given how complex their search engine is I'd guess the first option - it must be incredibly smart to know about contexts, versions of words, etc etc, but however it works, it seems to work very well.

This would be extremely helpful in providing relevant search results. Many words have associated or linked words, and it would be a shame not to include the best search results just because the search used a very related term, that happens not to be present in the best results.

So in your case, 2166136261 may be linked to a term like FNV, and the search includes results for the term FNV.

Comment: thanks, but it seems it is a little different in my case, i will update my question to illustrate that

Answer (score 0):

I think that it (maybe) depends on the search you've previously done. Because when I search 2166136261 on Google, I don't have the Wiki page on third position.
Here the result on google.com.br and also on google.com
[image]

Comment: thanks for mentioning searching history, I just try in incognito mode on google.hk, the Wiki page still shows up but as the 10th but not the 3rd result.

Comment: I get it as the 10th result after never searching for it too.

Answer (score 0):

Google "knows" (through global search history and clickstream analysis) that Web pages that are relevant to queries about "FNV hashing" also often contain the significant (i.e. otherwise rare) term '2166136261'. Therefore, Google infers that these terms are 'synonyms'. It expands your original query to include synonyms (this is sometime called query rewriting).